# how do i compile a C++program to work in the windows operating system using g++ for linux?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, g++

I am new to writing programs in c++ and i want to know if there is a way to export it to a windows format. Also what is a good way to learn objective-c, is it very different from c++? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's probably best not to ask two questions at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using mingw32 you can cross compile for windows. See http://www.mingw.org/wiki/LinuxCrossMinGW

Comment: No, not cygwin. cygwin is intended to be used on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Objective C is very different from C++.  It's mainstream use (that I know of) is for Apple platforms.  I'm sure there are others, but this is the most common that I have seen.

MinGw32 is the way that you would cross compile *on* a Linux platform to target Windows.

If you want to compile using gcc *on* the Windows platform, and be compatible with Linux libraries, you can use mingw32/MSys or Cygwin.

If you simply want to develop using gcc on Windows, ignoring any Posix(/Linux standard libraries) compatibility, then there are many options available to you.  A popular method would be to download and install Eclipse for C++/CDT.  It might use one of Cygwin or Mingw32 under the covers - not sure.

Answer (score 0):

> The Objective-C language is a simple computer language designed to enable sophisticated object-oriented programming. Objective-C is defined as a small but powerful set of extensions to the standard ANSI C language. Its additions to C are mostly based on Smalltalk, one of the first object-oriented programming languages. Objective-C is designed to give C full object-oriented programming capabilities, and to do so in a simple and straightforward way.

[For reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)

You can use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to code/compile the same code on a windows environment

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to programming I would just try to write something working on both *nix and windows, and compile it directly on Windows if needed.